# How to make CSS and other fonts show on default Chrome Printing

Tags: google-chrome, printing, php, html, css

I'm printing a page of my PHP application with the ( ctrl + P ) (default printing). How can i make sure that the CSS (tables, padding, cellspacing, background picture with opacity) are printed along with the sheet. I'm calling the CSS from another file.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web-browser should normally apply the CSS settings when printing. It shouldn't matter that the CSS is in a separate file rather than inline.

CSS allows for [different styling for printing](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) (or other media) - so some pages are deliberately made to print differently (e.g. omitting menus and breadcrumb trails etc).